# GCloud commands not working on Windows 10

Tags: sdk, command, hosting, gcloud

I have been on this for 3 days. I installed Google Cloud SDK, till now I have not been able to use it. It always get stuck when a command is ran. As an example when I want to login using this `gcloud auth login` and click enter, the command does not execute it will be there till eternity until I close the cmd.

If I run `gcloud init` the same thing happens. This cmd windows could remain like that without the command being executed. What am I to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report. Let's try a few commands to test the basic installation. This command should display help: "gcloud --help". This command should report no network problems: "gcloud info --run-diagnostics".

Comment: Thanks @Glenn. I have deployed it on another server